# Which CSS class is controlling these numbers being written?

Tags: jquery, css

I've got a jQuery CSS Gallery setup, Just playing about with the styles etc of it now. But I've got one issue with it, That issue is that the numbers 1,2,3 and 4 are appearing in the list. I dont want them adding. I've tried playing about with the CSS class and set the ol list-style to none. But it doesnt seem to have changed.

Anyone got any ideas?

Example here :

[Example](http://apili.net/catering-gallery/test.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this HTML in the source:

```
<a style="width:165px;">4</a>
```

Either you can indent the numbers with css:

```
.horinaja_pagination a
{
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Or replace the number with `&nbsp;`.

Either will work fine, but I'd recommed using the first solution as it's better for accessibility if some user has styles turned off.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. The HTML in the source must be written by the jQuery itself, as I cant find it anywhere else. The text-indent works a treat though many thanks

Comment: I agree, your solution is much better. Did not realize that the slider loses its pagination. Answer deleted!

Answer (score 0):

try to put pagination on false like this:

```
$('#demo').Horinaja({
    capture:'demo',
    delai:0.5,
    duree:6,
    pagination:false,
});
```

If you still want to show the circles but not the number you could try this (no guarantee that it will work:

Add this to your css:

```
ol.horinaja_pagination li a {
    display: none;
}
```